# Image Collection Join Error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, modis

In the below code, I want to join two image collections based on `system:time_start` property but it does not work and returns 0 element. Collections acquisition dates are same but they are different in acquisition hour so that causes error. Does anyone know any solution on this?

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/4acd9c3482cd89bc5f2f48e1a69cc490

```
var temp = mod11.select('LST_Day_1km')
.filterDate('2010', '2011')
.map(function(img){
  var time = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'))
  return img
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames())
  .set('time',time)
  })

var wat = ocean.select('chlor_a')
.filterDate('2010','2011')
.map(function(img){
  var time = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'))
  return img
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames())
  .set('time',time)
  })



var innerJoin = ee.Join.inner();

var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

var innerJoinData = innerJoin.apply(temp, wat, filter);

var datasets =  ee.ImageCollection(innerJoinData.map(function(img){
  return ee.Image.cat(img.get('primary'), img.get('secondary'))
  .copyProperties(img,img.propertyNames())
}));


print(datasets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ee.Filter.maxDifference()`. There's an example in the [user guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/joins_save_best):

```
// Define a max difference filter to compare timestamps.
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});
```